# Push notification from AWS SNS console

Tags: ios, push-notification, amazon-sns

I'm trying to get notification work on my ios app using SNS. I follow the instruction on AWS mobile hub integration page. I checked the SNS page and I can see my app subscribes to the topic. But when I publish notification from the console by selecting the topic, my app does not get any notification. I've been trying for hours now and I appreciate any clue and theory on this matter.

This is the output log from my app after subscribing to the topic :

```
 <SubscribeResponse xmlns="http://sns.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-03-31/">
    <SubscribeResult>
    <SubscriptionArn>arn:aws:sns:****:NotifySharing:****</SubscriptionArn>
 </SubscribeResult>
 <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>***</RequestId>
    </ResponseMetadata>
 </SubscribeResponse>
```

I replaced some info with **** just to make sure that I'm not disclosing sensitive data. Anyway, what could be the problem?

This is my code that does subscription :

```
class PushNotificationHandler: NSObject {

  func setupPushManager() {
    let pushManager: AWSPushManager = AWSPushManager.defaultPushManager()
    pushManager.delegate = self
    pushManager.registerForPushNotifications()
    if let topicARNs = pushManager.topicARNs {
        pushManager.registerTopicARNs(topicARNs)
    }

    if pushManager.enabled {

        for topic in pushManager.topics {
            topic.subscribe()
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve the problem? If not, Have you enabled push notifications in your xcode capabilities? Are you using an actual device to test (not simulator)?

Comment: I did and i found out that I was using wrong certificate. Stupid of me.